# Why are these two objects linked? (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

My understanding of the following code is that I have one item, I add that item to an ArrayList, and I can modify both of their inventories individually. But when I test it, neither are correct. Can anyone help me understand why that may be?

```
int i = item.getInventory();
item.setInventory(i-numToBuy);
inv.getCart().add(item);
inv.getCart().get(inv.getCart().indexOf(item)).setInventory(numToBuy);
g.getShoppingCart().setText(inv.getCartString());
```

Comment: You are actually referencing to the same `item` object in the memory, both the item outside and the one you are getting by the index are referencing to the same physical object in the memory. Therefore your changes will stack, they won't occur independently.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually referencing to the same item object in the memory, both the item outside and the one you are getting by the index are referencing to the same physical object in the memory. Therefore your changes will stack, they won't occur independently. You either need to explicitly create two different item objects or "deep copy" the one you are having into an empty item object.